# "db.list_tables(library='taq')" returns an empty list. Why?

Tags: python, wrds

I'm trying to download data from wrds-taq dataset(taq_1993,...,taq_2014 products).

`[x for x in db.list_libraries() if 'taq' in x]`  returns:

`['taq', 'taqm_2012', 'taqm_2013', 'taqm_2014', 'taqm_2015', 'taqm_2016', 'taqm_2017', 'taqm_2018', 'taqm_2019', 'taqm_2020', 'taqm_2021', 'taqmsamp', 'taqmsec', 'taqsamp']`

But then `db.list_tables(library='taq')` returns an empty list. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I get an empty list, but this may be because I don't have access to TAQ. Also it looks like the TAQ tables are [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-foreign-data.html) and the `list_tables()` function might not show such tables. (Many tables in the WRDS database are views, but they're still views on tables found within the `wrds` database.)